# Analysis Services Execute DDL Task connect string for Power BI XMLA endpoint

Tags: ssis, powerbi, ssas-tabular

We have power bi premium and an XMLA endpoint enabled.

I am trying to refresh partition in the dataset using a TMSL script.

The microsoft doco says this should work with "Analysis Services Execute DDL Task in SSIS."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/tabular-model-scripting-language-tmsl-reference?view=azure-analysis-services-current

I can connect in SSIS (see below) but when i run the DDL Task with this conection I get a connection string is not valid messaage.

any help appreciated.

thanks

Error: 0x0 at Analysis Services Execute DDL Task, Analysis Services Execute DDL Task: The connection string is not valid.
Error: 0x0 at Analysis Services Execute DDL Task, Analysis Services Execute DDL Task: Execution of DDL failed.
Task failed: Analysis Services Execute DDL Tas

[image: Connection Manaager image]

Answer (score 0):

Connecting with a service principal
If you've enabled tenant settings to allow service principals to use Power BI APIs, as described in Enable service principals, you can connect to an XMLA endpoint by using a service principal. Keep in mind the service principal requires the same level of access permissions at the workspace or dataset level as regular users.

To use a service principal, be sure to specify the application identity information in the connection string as:

User ID=app:appid@tenantid
Password=
For example:

Data Source=powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/Contoso;Initial Catalog=PowerBI_Dataset;User ID=app:91ab91bb-6b32-4f6d-8bbc-97a0f9f8906b@19373176-316e-4dc7-834c-328902628ad4;Password=6drX...;

If you receive the following error:

"We cannot connect to the dataset due to incomplete account information. For service principals, make sure you specify the tenant ID together with the app ID using the format app:@, then try again."

Make sure you specify the tenant ID together with the app ID using the correct format.

It's also valid to specify the app ID without the tenant ID. However, in this case, you must replace the myorg alias in the data source URL with the actual tenant ID. Power BI can then locate the service principal in the correct tenant. But, as a best practice, use the myorg alias and specify the tenant ID together with the app ID in the User ID parameter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/troubleshoot-xmla-endpoint#connecting-with-a-service-principal